# How to serialize/deserialize case classes from a spark dataset to/from s3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Let's say I have a Dataset[MyData] where MyData is defined as:
`case class MyData(id: String, listA: List[SomeOtherCaseClass])`

I want to save the data to s3 and load back later with MyData case class.
I know case class data is serializable. But is it possible to do like:

```
myData.write.xxxx("s3://someBucket/some")

// later
val myloadedData: Dataset[MyData] = spark.read.yyyy("s3://someBucket/some", MyData)
```

Comment: I didn't know that this is already possible. I just tested `myData.write.orc(...)` and `spark.read.orc(...).as[MyData]` and got exactly what I want! Thank you!

Comment: If you copy and paste your comment as an answer, I will check it as an answer. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does *serialization* means for you?

Because you only need to do exactly what you showed, choosing any [available format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter) you like, e.g. `csv`, `json`, `parquet`, `orc`, ...
*(I would recommend doing a [benchmarking](https://es.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/performance-update-when-apache-orc-met-apache-spark-81023199) between **ORC** and **Parquet** for your data, to see which one works better for you).*

```
myData.write.orc("s3://someBucket/somePath")
```

And, when reading, just use the same format to get a `DataFrame` back, which you can cast to a `Dataset[MyData]` using the [`as[T]` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@as[U](implicitevidence$2:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]).

```
val myloadedData: Dataset[MyData] = spark.read.orc("s3://someBucket/somePath").as[MyData]
```

Or, your question was how to connect to **S3**? - If so, if you are running from **EMR** then everything will be setup already. You only need to prepend your path with `s3://`, as you already did.